# Right click on taskbar icon then select on popupmenu

Tags: python, pywinauto

This is my code to right click on the app selected  :

```py
import pywinauto
#import time
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer.exe") 
taskbar = app.window(class_name="Shell_TrayWnd") 
taskbar.child_window(title="myApp").click_input(button='right') 
app.PopupMenu.MenuClick("Open")
```

But then I can't choose "Open" on the popupmenu, which is Open or Exit.
Everything work until the `MenuClick()`.
How can I do that ?

Comment: What is the module you are working with? Also can you format your code with triple backticks(\`\`\`)?

Comment: I am using the Application module, but if you know otherwise it's okay, I'll try everything at that point. Sorry if I misunderstood your question, did I ?

Comment: Taskbar's owner process is `explorer.exe` while popup menu is owned by target application process. So you have to connect by executable name and try it for another `Application` object after popup menu is shown. Another option is to try `Desktop(backend="uia")` instead of `Application(backend="uia")`.